# Calculating the area of overlap of two functions

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, calculus

I have two functions. I am giving here the basic structure only, as they have quite a few parameters each to adjust their exact shape.

For example, `y = sin(.1*pi*x)^2` and `y = e^-(x-5)^2`.

The question is how much area of the sine is captured by the `e` function:

[image]

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by overlap or intersect. Do you want to calculate an integral for `h(x)=min(f(x),g(x))`?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to be clever and recursively find the points of intersection, but that turned out to be a lot more work than was necessary.

As [`n.m.` pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524355/calculating-the-area-of-overlap-of-two-functions?noredirect=1#comment56790652_34524355), you want the integral from `a` to `b` of `min(f, g)`. Since you're integrating by approximation, you're already stepping through the interval, meaning you can check at each step which function is greater and compute the area of the current trapezoid.

**Simple implementation in C**:

```
#define SLICES 10000

/*
 *  Computes the integral of min(f, g) on [a, b].
 *  
 *  Intended use is for when f and g are both non-negative, real-valued
 *  functions of one variable.
 *
 *  That is, f: R -> R and g: R -> R.
 *
 *  Assumes b ≥ a.
 *
 *  @param  a   left boundary of interval to integrate over
 *  @param  b   right boundary of interval to integrate over
 *  @param  f   function accepting one double argument which returns a double
 *  @param  g   function accepting one double argument which returns a double
 *  @return     integral of min(f, g) on [a, b]
 */
double minIntegrate (double a, double b, double (*f)(double), double (*g)(double)) {
    double area = 0.0;

    // the height of each trapezoid
    double deltaX = (b - a) / SLICES;

    /*
     *  We are integrating by partitioning the interval into SLICES pieces, then
     *  adding the areas of the trapezoids formed to our running total.
     *  To save a computation, we can cache the last side encountered.
     *  That is, let lastSide be the minimum of f(x) and g(x), where x was the
     *  previous "fence post" (side of the trapezoid) encountered.
     *  Initialize lastSide with the minimum of f and g at the left boundary.
     */
    double lastSide = min(f(a), g(a));

    // The loop starts at 1 since we already have the last (trapezoid) side 
    // for the 0th fencepost.
    for (int i = 1; i <= SLICES; i++) {
        double fencePost = a + (i * deltaX);
        double currentSide = min(f(fencePost), g(fencePost));

        area += trapezoid(lastSide, currentSide, deltaX);

        lastSide = currentSide;
    }

    return area;
}

/*
 *  Computes the area of a trapezoid with bases `a` and `b` and height `height`.
 */
double trapezoid (double a, double b, double height) {
    return h * (a + b) / 2.0;
}
```

Comment: Can you make it trazoidal? and start from 0, maybe.

Comment: @Bob__ starting at the 1st jump allows you to cache the last step you took outside the for-loop more easily.

Comment: I don't understand what `min(f, g)` means. Amazingly, it turns up in half the real analysis textbooks I google, but is not explained, and doesn't show up at all in the other half.

Comment: @Almeisan: It means to take the minimal value between f(x) and g(x)... so that min(4,1) = 1

Comment: Wow, that's so simple. I only needed to do the y for both, then check which one is lower, then use that one. Four more lines of code. Don't know why I tried to think about all kinds of complex stuff. I guess I got trained that way when I took calc classes. Ofc when I am already walking over the curve, slicing it, it is easy to check which one of the functions is lower. Thanks.

Comment: @Almeisan I cleaned up the code. There were two small mistakes which I fixed. 1. `double lastSide = min(f(a), g(a));` I had written `min(f(a), f(b))`, which was wrong. 2. `i <= GAP;` I forgot to include the last trapezoid.

Comment: @Almeisan is the answer no longer sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something really, really simple, why don't you do [Monte Carlo Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration)?

Use the fact that the functions are easy to calculate to sample a large number of points. For each point, check whether it's below 0, 1, or 2 of the curves.

You might have some fiddling to find the boundaries for the sampling, but this method will work for a variety of curves.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your exponential is actually of the form e^-(x-5)^2 so that the exponential decays to zero at plus/minus infinity.

Given that, your integral would be most quickly and accurately calculated by something called [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature). There are a few types of common integrals which have very simple solutions using different polynomials (Hermite, Legendre, etc.). Yours specifically looks like it could be solved using [Gauss-Hermite quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it is `e^-(x-5)^2`, I forgot it initially, edited it in, but it seems it reverted.

Comment: So was I correct in understanding which integral you're trying to calculate, namely, some arbitrary function, f(x), times a Gaussian function, integrated from x=-infinity to x=infinity?

Comment: No. There is four cases. 1) `e` entirely below the sine, integrate just the `e`, a problem I solved. 2) `e` is offset. There are three intersections.  First where the sine is zero, cuts off the `e` tail. Then the sine is above the `e`. So this area part from `x1` where sine is 0 is the `e` function up to `x2`for the the the second intersection. For the next part, the `e` is above the sine. So I need to integrate sine from x2 to x3 (right point for sine is 0). Then there's the case `e` captures area from both the sine on the left and right.

Comment: The problem I have is that I don't know how to find the x values for the intercepts.

Comment: Case four, the tip of the `e` gets above the sine in the middle, stays below otherwise. In that case you would integrate e from `x1` to `x4`, subtract `e` from `x2` to `x3`, add back sine from `x2` to `x3`.

Comment: If it's just the intercepts you need then you could try using the Newton-Raphson or Secant methods for root finding where you want the roots of f(x)=p(x)-q(x). You'll need to have some idea of where the roots are and how many but if you can guess these then both these methods will converge in a matter of 5 or 6 iterations to double precision.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That sounds helpful. I added a picture in the opening post, because indeed this was confusing to explain. It's even confusing me and I said some wrong things. Going for a run now, ill check back later and hopefully start solving the problem.

Comment: Here is a [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+exp%28-x^2%29-sin%282x%29^2) of what you'd be looking at. The roots of this function are the intercepts of the sine and exponential functions and they look pretty straight forward to solve with either of the methods I mentioned.

Comment: How can I delete this?

Comment: Delete your question?